# Bootstrap slider - distance between elements and labels

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-slider

I've a problem in bootstrap slider, how can I choose the distance between elements and labels?
Here is my code. Thanks.

```
 <input id="ex13" type="text" data-slider-ticks="[0, 100, 200, 300, 400]"
                           data-slider-ticks-snap-bounds="30"
                           data-slider-ticks-labels="['$0', '$100', '$200', '$300', '$400']"/>


var slider = new Slider("#ex13", {
    ticks: [10, 50, 100, 200, 400, 800],
    ticks_labels: ['10', '50', '$200', '$300', '$400'],
    ticks_snap_bounds: 0
});
```

Comment: Use `ticks_positions`: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider#options